# How to create Column in Center of App with Left/Right margins?

Tags: flutter, dart

im new to Flutter. I have started learning a few days ago and am trying to grasp the concept of Rows and Columns.

I made a simple Page like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xSl8.png).

To explain my code I first make a Column to put everything in.
Then i use a Row for the TopBar, and then another Row to put the things into the body, so that i can put a Column in the center of the Page, with a bit of space on both sides of it. I then pack Text and Button in a Column and insert it into the Column in the Middle of the Page.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: MainPage(),
));


class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color Color1 = const Color.fromRGBO(204, 126, 185, 100);
    Color Color2 = const Color.fromRGBO(140, 235, 203, 100);
    Color Color3 = const Color.fromRGBO(227, 225, 204, 100);
    Color Color4 = const Color.fromRGBO(89, 130, 145, 100);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 50.0, 0, 0),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    child: Image.asset('assets/MenuIcon.png'),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 50.0, 20.0, 0),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    child: Image.asset('assets/SearchIcon.png'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Divider(height: 50,),
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Container(),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 5,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              "Erwachsen werden",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontSize: 28.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: double.infinity,
                              child: ButtonTheme(
                                minWidth: 300,
                                height: 70,
                                child: FlatButton(
                                  shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(13.0),
                                      ),
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                  color: Color1,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),

                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              "Glückliches Leben",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontSize: 28.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: double.infinity,
                              child: ButtonTheme(
                                minWidth: 300,
                                height: 70,
                                child: FlatButton(
                                  shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(13.0),
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                  color: Color2,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              "Ab in das Leben",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontSize: 28.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: double.infinity,
                                child: ButtonTheme(
                                  minWidth: 300,
                                  height: 70,
                                  child: FlatButton(
                                    shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(13.0),
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () {},
                                    color: Color3,
                                  ),
                                )
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              "Alleine Leben",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontSize: 28.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: double.infinity,
                              child: ButtonTheme(
                                minWidth: 300,
                                height: 70,
                                child: FlatButton(
                                  shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(13.0),
                                      ),
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                  color: Color4,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex:1,
                    child: Container(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I feel like there is a lot of unnecessary Coding, but i can't seem to be able to improve it, with it working properly.

Can anybody Help improve my code?
Simply what i want to achieve is a Column in the middle of the body with margin to the left and right of the screen, without a million lines of code.

Comment: hi, if my answer helped you can you accept my answer as correct one.

Answer (score 2):

`Scaffold` by default has an parameter for `AppBar()` use that for your app bar

and as per your layout I will suggest to use `ListView()` instead of `Column()`

using `Listview` will automatically scroll your page if length of your page extends
and also has an parameter as `padding` using which you can add space on your left and right side

refer below mentioned code structure

```
Scaffold(
  appbar: AppBar(),
  body: ListView(
           padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:12.0,right:12.0),
           children: <Widget>[
                   //your list of widgets here
                      ],
        )
)
```

Comment: Ok i will try that thank you! I'd love to give you an upvote, sadly i dont have the rep to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
[Code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dWLk.png)

```
Center(
            child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                height: 400,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Material(
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      child: Image.asset(
                        "assets/images/logo.png",
                        height: 100,
                        width: 200,
                      ),
                    ),
                    //email


                TextFormField(
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: "Light",
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  ),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  cursorColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Username',
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),

                TextFormField(
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: "Light",
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  ),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                  cursorColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  obscureText: passwordVisible,
                  controller: _passwordController,

                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Password',
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                Container(
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text(
                      "Login",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontFamily: "Light",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )),
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed unnecessary code ! It may help you !

```
Color color1 = const Color.fromRGBO(204, 126, 185, 100);

  Color color2 = const Color.fromRGBO(140, 235, 203, 100);

  Color color3 = const Color.fromRGBO(227, 225, 204, 100);

  Color color4 = const Color.fromRGBO(89, 130, 145, 100);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 50.0, 0, 0),
                  child: SizedBox(
//                     child: Image.asset('assets/MenuIcon.png'),
                    child:Icon(Icons.menu,color:Colors.black)
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 50.0, 20.0, 0),
                  child: SizedBox(
//                     child: Image.asset('assets/SearchIcon.png')
                    child:Icon(Icons.search,color:Colors.black)
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:50,right:50),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisSize:MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "Erwachsen werden",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 28.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: ButtonTheme(
                        minWidth: 300,
                        height: 70,
                        child: FlatButton(
                            shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(13.0),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {},
                            color: color1,
                            child: Text('Button')),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                    Text(
                      "Glückliches Leben",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 28.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: ButtonTheme(
                        minWidth: 300,
                        height: 70,
                        child: FlatButton(
                            shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(13.0),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {},
                            color: color2,
                            child: Text('Button')),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                    Text(
                      "Ab in das Leben",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 28.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                    SizedBox(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: ButtonTheme(
                          minWidth: 300,
                          height: 70,
                          child: FlatButton(
                              shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(13.0),
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {},
                              color: color3,
                              child: Text('Button')),
                        )),
                    SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                    Text(
                      "Alleine Leben",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 28.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: ButtonTheme(
                        minWidth: 300,
                        height: 70,
                        child: FlatButton(
                            shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(13.0),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {},
                            color: color4,
                            child: Text('Button')),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I see you used Padding on the column instead of an extra Row. Seems much more intuitive.

Comment: Hm ! If helped you don't forget to accept the answer or wait for someone will give you more flexible way ! Have a good day !